# Git won't give status or push

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I´m trying to add a file to my git account. I have already pushed it to git once, but I have edited again, and want to push the updated file to git. I´m very(!!) new to this, so it is probably me who is doing something completely wrong. But it worked the first time I did it, (and it is how my teacher wanted me to do..).

I have tried to save my file in VSCODE. Then in the terminal I'm writing git status. But the output in the terminal then says: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

If i try: git add file.py it says the same thing..
Can someone please try to help me fix what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: You need to cd into a folder that is part of a git repo.

Comment: your vscode project needs to be a git repository to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you are seeing:

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

means that the current directory in which the terminal is in is not actually inside your Git project.  This could be happening for several reasons.  If the terminal is *not* inside your project, then you should `cd` to get inside the project, and try doing `git status` again.  If the terminal *is* inside your project, and you are still seeing this message, then it could be that you initialized Git in the wrong location, or maybe at the wrong level of your project.  Typically, you would want your Git folder to start at the root level of your project, so that all project files can potentially be added to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not in the folder where you cloned your repository.

The **.git** is a hidden folder contained in the root of a repository. That message shows that you are not in a folder/sub-folder which the root contains a **.git** folder.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to git I don't know your experience with versioning system at all.

With git you should do the following steps to achieve what you want:

1. Create a git repository in you versioning system (you can do this online e.g. on https://github.com)
2. Checkout your git repository you just created on your local machine (normally done on command line via 'git clone ...'. Any newer versioning system supporting git will provide you the terminal command
3. After checkout you will find a local copy of your repo in your file system. Use command line and navigate into that folder.
4. Once you are in that folder you are able to run all git commands you would, like changing files here and pushing them.
5. After successful push double check on the versioning system. It should be the same folder/files as in your local copy.

One of these points you are missing while trying to apply your git command. Git commands can only be applied from command line when you are in a checked out repository folder. Anywhere else git will not work.

Don't hesitate to ask if get stucked.

R4FT3R